# How to return an EF object as WCF method result

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I'm working with EF and WCF.
I would like use the object generated by EF as object returned from a web service method.
In the OperationContract method I do something like this:

```
try
{
   b = (from bon in this.znDbContext.BonSet
        where bon.IdPr == pa.IdPr
        select bon).First();    
}
catch (InvalidOperationException) { }

return b;
```

If I invoke the web service method I will receive the following error message:

> Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline
>   or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the
>   proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for
>   more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring
>   to default configuration, or refreshing the service.

Searching on google I've found an solution to resolve this problem. This statement has been added:

```
this.znDbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

In this way the client receive an response from web service method but every inner object has null value.
If I remove the previous statement and perform a copy of the object (field by field) the client receive the object with inner objects set correctly (i.e. boni.User).
For example I do:

```
boni = new Bon();
User u = new User();
boni.IdPr = b.IdPr;
boni.Date = b.Date;
boni.System = b.System;
u.Id = b.User.Id;
u.Name = b.User.Name;
u.Login = b.User.Login;
boni.User = u;
return boni;
```

There is a way to return a complete object with all inner object without perform something like a "clone" operation?
I would like something to detaching object from DbContext to obtain a new object avoiding a manual copy operation.

A theoretical explaination of the reason of the issue is very welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This issue is by design when you mixup ORM proxies with DTOs. This problem/solution is common in WCF and also applies to any other ORM such as nHibernate.*

If you fetch an entity from the ORM it usually returns a proxy which is capable of lazy-loading data from the db. For example, it will only load the actual data for a property when you first access it.
That means, that if you fetch a "Bon" object from EM it will give you an "BonProxy" object. Obviously "BonProxy" was not expected in the DataContract (and you can also not pass it down to the client as you would not be able to do any further lazy loading client side)

Solution:
**Turn your complex entities into DTOs** (i.e. doing the field to field copy) and just send DTOs over the wire. This is also necessary for the serialisation - you may control it to avoid circular references.

Comment: I've used this external tool to auto generate DTOs object: http://entitiestodtos.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20EntitiesToDTOs.v3.%2a&referringTitle=Using%20EntitiesToDTOs
At now works very well.
I hope that it can be useful.